# iPhone app crashes when a segue returns after trying to save search data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I'm using storyboarding to layout the interface for a proposed app.  I've got a button that segues into a table view controller with a search bar controller on top.  I'm following one of Apple's very basic examples on how to do a search found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#samplecode/TableSearch/Listings/MainViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848-MainViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6).  This example uses a single table view controller and saves the search term data to be retrieved on subsequent views.  The search data is saved using this code (I'm also including the object definitions):

```
@interface SearchTableViewController : UITableViewController {
  NSMutableArray *listOfLists;
  NSMutableArray *filteredListOfLists;
  NSString *savedSearchTerm;
  NSInteger savedScopeButtonIndex;
  BOOL searchWasActive;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *listOfLists;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *filteredListOfLists;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *savedSearchTerm;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger savedScopeButtonIndex;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL searchWasActive;
@end

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
  // save the state of the search UI so that it can be restored if the view is re-created
  self.searchWasActive = [self.searchDisplayController isActive];
  self.savedSearchTerm = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text];
  self.savedScopeButtonIndex = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex];
}
```

If I comment out the three core lines for saving the data, everything works as it should (with the exception of remembering the search object's status).  What I think is happening is that the view is getting "destroyed" as part of the segue (probably before the viewDidDisappear method is called) so "self" is no longer available.

What is the correct / best way of solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
   setValue:searchDisplayController.searchBar.text 
     forKey:"SavedSearchTerm"];
```

and

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
   valueForKey:"SavedSearchTerm"];
```

?

Doing this in `viewWillDisappear` will ensure that the objects are still there.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I think that doing something like that will ultimately work / and / or using AppDelegate which I've been exploring as an option as well.

Comment: I just figured out that if I place the code in the prepareForSegue method of the table view controller, it works.  I'm guessing that for some things, the prepareForSegue needs to be used instead of the viewDidDisappear method.